# Determine all vector subspaces of the real vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm being asked to determine "all vector subspaces of the $\mathbb{R}$ vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$". What does that even mean? Isn't it simply the $\operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
1\\0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
0\\1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$?

Comment: Yes, but maybe it is asking for a more geometrical answer...

Comment: Example answer: The $x$-axis is a subspace of the plane. This is just $\text{span}\{(1,0)\}$.

Comment: The 2 dimensional subspace and 0 dimension subspace are trivial.  How would you describe the set of 1 dimension subspaces?  What would a basis of such a subspace look like?

Comment: For 1 dimension subspaces, it's either span(1,0) or span(0,1)? Is that right?

Comment: @mercurial span$\{(1,0)\}$ will only be the $x$-axis which is a subspace. How about span$\{(1,1)\}$? Is that a subspace? A line through the origin will be a subspace. How can you describe all lines that go through the origin?

Comment: @BryanUrizar thanks for your help thus far. However aren't all lines that go through the origin simply represented by the span of dimension 2, if I were to define a vector subspace of randomly chosen x and y such that (x,y) is an element of this 1-dimensional subspace?

Comment: @mercurial Well, any point on a given line is in any span for $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it doesn't exactly represent the line, but rather the entire space of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So if I were to choose a point on a given line and one that wasn't and calculated the addition it wouldn't be on the line anymore. However, if you were to look at the subspaces of dimension 1 which are represented by span$\{(x,y)\}$ where $(x,y)$ is a nonzero vector it would be closed under addition. I suppose this comes down to sets really: Any line $L$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ but the reverse inclusion isn't true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span you give is $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself. It is a subspace but you're missing others. By the dimension theorem, there exists subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of dimension 0, 1 & 2. Does that help?